# Whats the difference between performant and reliable HA Profile in global configuration in anypoint studio? How does it vary in error handling?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCnaO.jpg
In the above snapshot, you can see the configuration available in setting up the global configuration for mule application. How do these Perforant and Reliable HA profiles affect the overall behavior of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the HA profiles have great impact on the behavior of your application. you will select Reliable profile when your application demands a zero tolerance for message loss. taken an example if you are building an integration for a banking system where you can't afford message loss. In your flow If a step fails for some reason, the transactional mechanism rolls back all previous processing events, then restarts the message-processing sequence. Connectors such as JMS, VM, and JDBC provide built-in transactional support, thus ensuring that messages get processed reliably.

on the contrary, If high performance is your primary goal (rather than reliability), you can configure a Mule cluster or an individual application for maximum performance using a performance profile. By implementing the performance profile for specific applications within a cluster, you can maximize the scalability of your deployments while deploying applications with different performance and reliability requirements in the same cluster. Performance profiles that you configure at the container level apply to all applications within the container. Application-level configuration overrides container-level configuration.

you can go through the following link for more info: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/mule-high-availability-ha-clusters#high-reliability-applications

Comment: Thanks @satish-chennupati